# How to get all documents and its count with mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

***I have a model called car This model has 21 document***

**but i want**

- get all documents count that match **make** property
- and create new array of objects with count property and its document

> example

**model**

```
const Car = new Schema({
  make: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  model: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  year: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  fuelType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  kilometers: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  details: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  photoUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

**and i want to get all documents with this shape**

```
const cars = [
  {
     make: 'Volkswagen',
     model: 'Tiguan',
     year: 2007,
     kilometers: 411019541855812,
     fuelType: 'Diesel',
     price: 14299,
     photoUrl: '/photos/cars/...jpg',
     details: 'Lorem ipsum..',
     count: 3
  },
  {
     ....
  }

]
```

the final purpose is printing the the car "model" and its count like that

```
"Volkswagen Tiguan (5)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregate to do this.

```js
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      make: "Volkswagen"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        make: "$make",
        model: "$model"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      make: "$_id.make",
      model: "$_id.model",
      count: "$count",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here first we `filter` the document based on the `make` and then `group` it based on `make` and `model`

Expected output

```js
[
  {
    "count": 2,
    "make": "Company 1",
    "model": "Model 1"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "make": "Company 1",
    "model": "Model 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks buddy for the solution i also solved that with aggregation with only $group and $project like that

Car.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$make",
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        make: { $max: "$make" },
        model: { $max: "$model" },
        ....
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        make: 1,
        model: 1,
        count: 1,
        .....
      },
    },
  ]);

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cars.find({}).select("make model count").then(cars =>{
   cars.forEach(car =>{
          Console.log(car.make ,car.model , car.count)
     })
})
```

Well , From your output , I believe that ,you just want make , model and count . So I added select property .if u want to retrieve all the property of ur car then u can remove tht select property from above